# "Invalid operands to binary expression"

Tags: c, if-statement, multidimensional-array, comparison

in my first year University class we have just started fiddling with arrays and on the worksheet I was given this code, which doesn't seem to work. I've been scanning and looking for a problem but nothing seems to fix it. Here is my code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(){

    int size = 10;
    float suspect[size]; //Declaring suspect array
    
    int sizeR = 3;
    int sizeC = 10;
    float criminals[sizeR][sizeC]; //Declaring criminals array

    //Read 10 input values into suspect array from keyboard
    printf("Enter the 10 chromosomes of the suspect separated by spaces: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        scanf(" %f", &suspect[i]);

    //Read multiple profiles of 10 values into criminals array from the keyboard
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeR; i++){
        printf("Enter the 10 chromosomes of the %dth criminal: \n", i+1);

    //Read 10 input values of a criminal into criminals array from the keyboard
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeC; j++)
        scanf(" %f", &criminals[i][j]);

    }

    //Match two profiles
    bool match = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if(suspect[i] != criminals[i]) //Error is in this line
            match = false;

    //Display matching result
    if (match)
        printf("The two profiles match! \n");
    else
        printf("The two profiles don't match! \n");

    return 0;
}
```

And when I run this code, I am returned with:

*error: invalid operands to binary expression ('float' and 'float [sizeC]')*

With the error being pointed to the != in the matching two profiles part. Excuse me if the solution is simple, coding is relatively new to me and I am struggling to find the solution to this particular problem using Google.

Comment: The error is telling you that you are trying to compare a `float` to an array. That obviously cannot work. Since `criminals` is a 2-dimensional array you need to pick one element from the second dimension as well

Comment: It should give the line number. Anyway, why your "suspects" and "criminals" are `float` at all? This is a bad idea, especially if you are trying to compare them.

Comment: Please explain your understanding of the data types of the two operand in `suspect[i] != criminals[i]` and what that line should do by your expectation.

Comment: @Yunnosch I expect it to return a print saying that the criminal array doesn't match the suspect array. The goal of the program is to compare two arrays and tell the user if the array entered matches the array on "the system"

Comment: @EugeneSh. The code is from a worksheet our University have supplied us for our practical, this wasn't written by me, only rewritten into VS

Comment: Note that "suspect" is a singular noun and "criminals" is a plural. This corresponds nicely to the difference in the dimensionality of the two arrays. So what do you want to compare with what exactly?

Comment: Hm, I seem to have phrased ambiguosly, so I split into smaller parts, starting with the simplest. Please explain your understanding of the data type of `suspect[i]`.

Comment: @Callum So obviously it wasn't "rewritten" properly as you are having errors.

Comment: @Yunnosch Honest truth is that I'm not really sure. We've kind of had arrays dumped on us with no elaboration on how they work. Our study is very independent and we get little assistance from our module leaders, which doesn't help when I'm extremely lost.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Probably, though I've scanned the document word for word and cannot find any difference in the document and what I have rewritten.

Comment: @Callum So back to the types question - what kind of input does the program expect? How the "chromosomes" look like?

Comment: @EugeneSh. The program expects 10 integer inputs in the same line separated by a space, which it then compares to another input of 10 integers in the same line separated by a space

e.g. 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Comment: What are you supposed to do with the worksheet? Are you supposed to run it as is? (Then what?) Are you supposed to fix it? (According to what specification?)

Comment: @Callum So you say "integer inputs". Meaning that having these as `floats` does not make any sense.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry my bad, the worksheet specifies an example test that uses decimal numbers, for testing I have been entering integers so that is why I referred to them as integers. Floats and Integers are both accepted inputs in the program

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. This is the part I have no answer for, the practicals our course have given us don't have an end goal, neither do they have to be handed in. And the sheet doesn't ask us to fix the program. I think the point of it is for us to get used to writing programs, which is a strange way of learning as I am not understanding the more advanced parts of C so far (advanced in my view being arrays)

Comment: Well, since the program as shown is invalid, the remaining option is to figure out a reasonable thing for it to do, and then fix it so that it does that thing. I would say a yes or no answer is not very reasonable. "Yes" means that the suspect is one of the known criminals (presumably DNA found at the crime scene matches one of the known profiles). Great, but not too useful. The police would like to know which one. Try providing this information in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this if statement

```
if(suspect[i] != criminals[i]) //Error is in this line
```

the expression `criminals[i]` is implicitly converted to the type `float *` because the original type of the expression before the conversion is `float[sizeC]`.

And moreover the expressions `suspect[i]` has the type `float`. That is there are compared an object of the type `float` with a pointer of the type `float *` that does not make a sense.

So the compiler issues the error message.

If you are going to compare the array `suspect` with elements of the two-dimensional array `criminals` you should use one more  inner for loop.